# Serilog Filter Expression: Filter expression doesn't work as expected with "... is not null"

Tags: c#, .net, serilog, serilog-expressions

I have configured my serilog configuration in appsetting.json
here is how I did :

```
 // Configuring Serilog


"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer", "Serilog.Expressions" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      },
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "connection string",
          "tableName": "Logs",
          "autoCreateSqlTable": true,
          "batchPostingLimit": 1,
          "period": "0:00:01",
          "columnOptions": {
            "AdditionalDataColumns": [
              {
                "ColumnName": "UserId",
                "DataType": "nvarchar",
                "DataLength": 256
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "connection string ",
          "tableName": "UserActivity",
          "autoCreateSqlTable": true,
          "batchPostingLimit": 1,
          "period": "0:00:01",
          "columnOptions": {
            "AdditionalDataColumns": [
              {
                "ColumnName": "UserId",
                "DataType": "nvarchar",
                "DataLength": 256
              }
            ]
          },
          "Properties": {
            "UserId": "UserId",
          },
          "Filter": [
            {
              "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
              "Args": {
                "Expression": "UserId is not null"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }

    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ]
  },
```

Here as you see there is two tables, one Logs table and the other is UserActivity. Logs table can contains any type of logs and it should store all the logs but,
I want to store only the logs with having `UserId` to the `UserActivity` table but it doesn't work as expected.
all the logs with and without having `UserId` are logged in both tables.

can anyone help what is the problem?

Comment: Hi! The `Filter` element isn't a supported child of the `Args` element, I'm not sure whether/how this would all be expressed in JSON. In general, the best way to develop a nontrivial Serilog configuration is to first get it working using the C# API (`WriteTo...` etc.), and then translate the result into JSON configuration. HTH!